# With sql service broker what happens if the target application crashes?

Tags: c#, sql-server-2008-r2, entity-framework-5, .net-4.5, service-broker

How will the target application get the messages send to it while it was unresponsive, stopped and restarting? Will they be sent again automatically when it comes back online?

How would you implement this with EF and C#? Where are the tutorials!

Comment: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522893(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 1):

Service Broker sends from SQL Server to SQL Server. The protocol used is fully resilient to crashes, messages stay in the sender's `sys.transmission_queue` until acknowledged by the target, and the target only acknowledges them after committing them into the destination service queue. SQL Server also handles everything related to transient failures: unresponsive destination, network partitioning, servicing/patching outages. All this is handled by SQL Server itself, as it guarantees Exactly Once In Order delivery.

Now what happens if your *application* crashes, ie. while processing a RECEIVE statement, is very simple: you interact with Service Broker through T-SQL, in a database transaction context. If the application crashes, the normal behavior of ACID database transactions kick in: since the transaction did not commit, it will be rolled back and the application will have a chance to process the message again, after restart.

So, from your application point of view, you only interact with a database, queues and tables and all, within a database transaction context. Your questions are the same as 'what happens to an INSERT if the application crashes?'

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, where are some code samples in c# on how to implement this, preferably using entity framework?